# float:right property on <p> which is inside a <div> is not working

Tags: css, alignment

I want to right align the number which is inside the tag

which is again inside the  tag.

```
    <div class="first">
      <a class="background-type1" >
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p class="pull-right">{{=val1}}</p>
      </a><a class="background-type2">
        <p>SOme other text</p>
       <p class="pull-right">{{=val2}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.pull-right {
  float: right;  
}
```

Need Help as what should I add to css so that so that val1and val 2 get right align to right of

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could put the values inside a `<span class="pull-right">` tag, like:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="first"> 
    <a class="background-type1">
        <p>Some text
            <span class="pull-right">1</span>
        </p>
      </a>
    <a class="background-type2">
        <p>Some other text
             <span class="pull-right">2</span>
        </p>
      </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/sJQu4/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted exactly the same way you have shown. But when I apply exactly, its still floating the val1 and val2 down the line. I also tried to give the width to <a> and to <p> even. Still not giving expected result. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The floated element needs to precede or be a child of the element you want it floated next to. You would be better off doing a `float:left` on the first paragraph given the current source order, or just moving the `<p class="pull-right">` before the other `<p>` in the HTML.

Comment: Super duper  hit answer :) Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/62dDV/

```
.pull-right { float: right; }
.first{ border: 1px solid red; }
p{ border: 1px solid silver; display: inline-block; }
a{ border: 1px solid green; display: block; }
```